# Cannot resolve symbol using App engine's sample code for Java Mail

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I have set up an app engine backend in my Android project using Android Studio successfully by following the hello world guide [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloWorld). The app can communicate with the backend server. My next step is code the backend such that it can send emails. I am following the official guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/). However, I am facing an issue with the following import statements, which cannot be resolved.

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

I am really puzzled why this is the case as the guide specifically says "All of the JavaMail classes you need are included with the App Engine SDK. Do not add Oracle®'s JavaMail JARs to your app; if you do, the app will throw exceptions."

I have App Engine SDK included in the project, else the hello world program wouldn't have worked. I can't figure out why the import statements are not resolving.

Here is my build.gradle file for reference. Would appreciate your help.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.14'
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter();
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}
appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about GAE, but do you need a dependency for JavaMail?

Comment: Hi Bill, yeah it's necessary to have a dependency for JavaMail, but it is bundled with the GAE SDK, and the phrasing of the guide suggested that there was no extra action needed ("All of the JavaMail classes you need are included with the App Engine SDK"). However, it turns out that it is insufficient to simply have the appengineSdk dependency. I'll elaborate in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I managed to solve the issue after a few hours by adding *one* extra line in the build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'   
}
```

So it turns out that simply having

```
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
```

was not sufficient. I had the impression that it was sufficient because I could run the hello world program just fine (i.e. deploying to the backend using GAE's tools worked, which implies that the sdk dependency was registered). However, when I tried calling specific libraries from within the sdk itself within the Java code, they could not be resolved.

The fix was to add a **compilation dependency.**

```
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.18'
```

I was not able to find the information from the official docs though. In fact, I wouldn't have known how to phrase the compilation dependency properly if not for [this article](http://rominirani.com/2014/08/15/gradle-tutorial-part-5-gradle-app-engine-plugin/) and the [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk).

Hopefully this helps anyone using the GAE libraries in their code.